# Why does the HMC sampler return negative values for hyperparameters that need to be positive? [older GPflow versions before 1.0]

Tags: gpflow

I'd like to build a GP with marginalized hyperparameters.

I have seen that this is possible with the HMC sampler provided in gpflow from [this notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/mcmc.ipynb)

However, when I tried to run the following code as a first step of this (*NOTE* this is on gpflow 0.5, an older version), the returned samples are negative, even though the lengthscale and variance need to be positive (negative values would be meaningless).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import gpflow
from gpflow import hmc

X = np.linspace(-3, 3, 20)
Y = np.random.exponential(np.sin(X) ** 2)
Y = (Y - np.mean(Y)) / np.std(Y)

k = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(1, lengthscales=.2, ARD=False)
m = gpflow.gpr.GPR(X[:, None], Y[:, None], k)
m.kern.lengthscales.prior = gpflow.priors.Gamma(1., 1.)
m.kern.variance.prior = gpflow.priors.Gamma(1., 1.)

# dont want likelihood be a hyperparam now so fixed
m.likelihood.variance = 1e-6
m.likelihood.variance.fixed = True

m.optimize(maxiter=1000)

samples = m.sample(500)
print(samples)
```

Output:

```
[[-0.43764571 -0.22753325]
 [-0.50418501 -0.11070128]
 [-0.5932655   0.00821438]
 [-0.70217714  0.05077999]
 [-0.77745654  0.09362291]
 [-0.79404456  0.13649446]
 [-0.83989415  0.27118385]
 [-0.90355789  0.29589641]
...
```

I don't know too much in detail about HMC sampling but I would expect that the sampled posterior hyperparameters are positive, I've checked the code and it seems maybe related to the Log1pe transform, though I failed to figure it out myself.
Any hint on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you specified *which* GPflow version you are using - especially given that from the output you posted it looks like you are using a *really* old version of GPflow (pre-1.0), and this is actually something that got improved since. What is happening here (in old GPflow) is that the sample() method returns a single array S x P, where S is the number of samples, and P is the number of free parameters [e.g. for a M x M matrix parameter with lower-triangular transform (such as the Cholesky of the covariance of the approximate posterior, q_sqrt), only M * (M - 1)/2 parameters are actually stored and optimised!]. These are the values in the *unconstrained* space, i.e. they can take any value whatsoever. Transforms (see `gpflow.transforms` module) provide the mapping between this value (between plus/minus infinity) and the constrained value (e.g. gpflow.transforms.positive for lengthscales and variances). In old GPflow, the model provides a `get_samples_df()` method that takes the S x P array returned by `sample()` and returns a pandas DataFrame with columns for all the trainable parameters which would be what you want. Or, ideally, you would just use a recent version of GPflow, in which the HMC sampler directly returns the DataFrame!

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer, using `get_sample_df` solved the problem.